# date entries in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change the date and time of an entry in my wordpress database.

The only thing I see is this number:

date: 1434533564

This number appears as 17.06.2015 at 09:32 on my webpage.

And here is the database structure:

```
`date` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

How can I change time and date?

Thank you!

[image: db date]

Comment: It looks like a Unix time stamp. Now you know everything you need to know to figure out the solution

Answer (score 1):

Actually its a unix timestamp..
You can use this function to see the actual date time :

select FROM_UNIXTIME(1434533564);

To change value you have to pass the date like this:
UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2015-02-05 00:12:12")
It will store the data in the format -> 1423116732

Answer (score 1):

The date and time are stored as a timestamp. 1434533564 translates to 17 Jun 2015 09:32:44. You can easily change it in your website with PHP (`strtotime('+1 day', 1434533564)`) or with an online converter like http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm